# memory management for deeper background work

Tags: cocoa

Currently i do some job in class:

```
[userController startRegistrationForAllObjectsInFutureArrayForTableView:nil];
```

this is a function:

```
-(void) startRegistrationForAllObjectsInFutureArrayForTableView:(id)tableView;
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^(void) {
     ... some job here
});
```

So, job is going to background. But i still need release class after all job will completed.
So what is a way to solve it?
Currently i do as here:

```
    [userController retain];
    [userController startRegistrationForAllObjectsInFutureArrayForTableView:nil];
}
[userController release];
[pool drain], pool = nil;
```

But i'm not sure if it work correct and what happened when autorelease pool is absent.
Tnx